# Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-test, flutter-plugin

HOPE YOU GO VERY WELL !!

I'm currently working on a control pad pannel for a robot control
i'm working for the flutter mobile part so than i'm facing this error :

Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:control_pad

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
lib/main.dart:77:5: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'StreamSubscription' w
hich excludes null.

- 'StreamSubscription' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'ScanResult' is from 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.d

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[flutter error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgrma.png)

i really need your help

Thanks!

Comment: There are hundreds of solutions for this error. Why don't you first visit https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety as directed by the error message?

Comment: yeah i visited it and tried some solution from the official website , but unfortunately i'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

try this solution on Android Studio

1. GO Run->
   Edit Configurations.
2. Add on this line to
   Additional Run args

> --no-sound-null-safety

3. APPLY
4. OK

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKoCP.png)

Answer (score 0):

To run your project with --no-sound-null-safety add this line your main.dart file in top(first line) with comment..

// @dart=2.9

then run your project.

To read more : [Reference](https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/flutter-cannot-run-with-sound-null-safety-because-the-following-dependencies-dont-support-null-safety/)